# Update Function Does Not Update Table Entry

Tags: python, mysql

I have created a function, which is supposed to update an entry of a table. The entry is specified by the user. When I run the program I do not get any errors. The entry that was supposed to have been `UPDATED` was not.

```
def updateEnc(pos, key):
    my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
    if pos.upper() == "NAME":
        sql = "UPDATE encounter SET name = %s WHERE id = %s"
        id = key
        name = (input("Enter name: "))
        my_cursor.execute(sql, name, id)
        mydb.commit() #mydb = my database
    elif pos.upper() == "DESCRIPTION":
        sql = "UPDATE encounter SET description = %s WHERE id = %s"
        id = key
        description = input("Enter description: ")
        my_cursor.execute(sql, description, id)
        mydb.commit()
```

The table is filled like so:

```
name: change
description: keep
id: 1

name: keep2
description: keep3
id: 2
```

After I call the `UPDATE` function it should look like this:

```
name: change
description: keep
id: 1

name: keep2
description: keep3
id: 2
```

But even so, it does not `UPDATE`

Thank you for your time. Have a great rest of the day!

Comment: Your "after the update it should look like"  doesn't look any different than the "before". If your using a "rows affected" check of some sort to determine if the update was successful, keep in mind that by default MySQL reports only the rows actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a connection to a database and begin making queries, they are a part of transaction which is not committed to the database until a method is called which "commits" the changes. The exact syntax for this method depends on what you are using to connect to your database but in general it's of the form `connection.commit()`.

[MySQL docs where this is explained in more detail](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)

If you have included this line outside of what you have posted here please add the rest of the relevant code to your question.